# "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH% when using mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to use mongodb driver.But I get the following error:

> go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/vendor/github.com/DataDog/zstd
>   exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

Comment: What Operating System are you building on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your library depends on `gcc` to run.

## 1. Linux/Containers

If you are running in a container, you can try two options:

1. you can build your app without `CGO` with the following command:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o yourBinary
```

2. You can try to install `gcc` into your container. If it is an alpine based container, run

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc
```

You could also need `musl-dev` package, but you should try without it first.

## 2. Windows

Since MacOS and most Linux distros come with GCC, I guess you could be using Windows. In this case, you need to install [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/).

Comment: I did install MinGW - it still throwing this error. Does this need to be configured a certain way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I ran into this problem too, About Alexey answer, on windows, you should install MinGW and add the path to win environment. You should follow [this](http://www.codebind.com/cprogramming/install-mingw-windows-10-gcc/). In case MinGW did not work, you can install [this](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) one which worked perfectly for me on windows.